# c++ ofstream file only displaying last line after while loop

Tags: c++, function, ofstream

I'm having a lot of trouble with a couple of my coding assignments and was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction. I apologize in advance if this question is posted elsewhere. I really didn't know how to phrase the question in order to find something similar. What the problem is is that I'm trying to run some numbers from a .txt file through a couple boolean functions which will the output the results to another .txt file. The problem I'm having is that it's only the last line that is being outputted to the outfile. I tried asking my professor about it and he couldn't figure it out with me (which frustrated me quite a bit).

This is my code and I uploaded an image to display the text file that was created.

if (!inFile) {

```
        cout << "error opening file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while (inFile) {
            (inFile >> hour >> min);
            (cout << hour << ":" << min << endl);
            bool validate_hour(hour);
            bool validate_minute(min);
            inFile.ignore(1);
        }

            outFile.open("time_Validation.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

            if (validate_hour(hour) == true && validate_minute(min) == true) {
                outFile << hour << ":" << min << " hour is valid and minute is valid\n";
            }

            else if (validate_hour(hour) == false && validate_minute(min) == true) {
                outFile << hour << ":" << min << " hour is invalid and minute is valid\n";
            }

            else if (validate_hour(hour) == true && validate_minute(min) == false)
            {
                outFile << hour << ":" << min << " hour is valid and minute is invalid\n";
            }

            else if (validate_hour(hour) == false && validate_minute(min) == false)
            {
                outFile << hour << ":" << min << " hour is invalid and minute is invalid\n";
            }

    outFile.close();
```

[This is what I'm getting. There should be a line for each of those pairs of numbers displayed in the time_validation.txt file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Zuo.jpg)

I appreciate any help you can give me to finish this lab. Thanks for looking.

Thank you everyone for your input. I changed the `while(inFile) to while (inFile >> hour >> min)` like it was suggested. Clearly I need more practice with while loops. Again thank you everyone who gave me advice, it really helped with the completion of my code.

Comment: Your code looks... weird. Why put the input and output in parentheses? Why declare function prototypes in the loop? And talking about the loop, don't do e.g. `while(inFile)` or `while (!inFile.eof())` as it will seldom work as expected. Instead do `while (inFile >> hour >> min)`. Also note that when reading numbers or string, the input operator `>>` skips leading whitespace (which includes newlines) so the `ignore` call is mot likely not needed.

Comment: Your `while()` loop processes the entire input file before even opening the output file. Then it simply uses the last values it read from the input file, revalidating them. You may want to put the output code *inside* your `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 outfile.open("time_validation.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
    while(!infile)
        cout << "file does not exist" << endl;
    while(infile)
    {
        infile >> hour >> min;
        if(validate_hour(hour))
            outfile << hour << " hour is valid ";
        else
            outfile << hour << " hour is invalid ";
        if(validate_minute(minute))
            outfile << minute << " minute is valid \n";
        else
            outfile << minute << " minute is invalid \n";
    }
```

something like this should work,since you have not posted full code, i cannot tell how many times program is writing in the file, as far as i can tell, you are giving output to the file only once after validating all the inputs, while you should give the output to the file for every input loop.